# Accessibility: Voice over read update label?

Tags: swift, swift3, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility-notification

How to force voice over in Accessibility read my updated label

For example,

```
var label.text = 1
```

Then after 2 sec I update label to 2

```
label.text = 2
```

But the voice over not interact with 2

any suggest ?

Comment: @the4kman That question addresses announcements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question you're asking is, "How do I alert the user to a change in content," you can choose among three solutions.

1. Post `UIAccessibilityNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, label)` to notify the system that the content has changed and force focus to the label.
2. Post `UIAccessibilityNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, "Your announcement")` to request that the system communicate the string to the user.
3. Assign the `UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently` trait to your label. The system will periodically announce changes to the content.

Comment: Hi can you please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008538/why-isnt-uiaccessibilitynotification-not-moving-to-correct-argument

Answer (score 2):

#### Swift 5:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: label)
```